# How to use embedded javascript to create a popup on 3rd party sites?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, popup

I'm creating a popup script that allows users to show a popup on their website (similar to SumoMe or OptinMonster).

What I'm missing is how do I get the popup to work on an external website?

Currently I know how to implement it on my own site, but it requires several lines of code, namely I need to have a DIV that contains my popup code (look at div id = popup below). Then I'm using Jquery to actually make the popup open up.

You can see an example of what I'm trying to do here: http://vyper.io/7-ecommerce-growth-hacks/

(Click the yellow button to see).

I'm trying to come up with an approach that works with ONE embedded javascript similar to how the other companies are doing it. So basically the page would include a

```
<script src="popup.js"></script>
```

and then link to the popup like

```
<a href="" class="popup>Click here to open the popup!</a>
```

I hope I'm being clear. How should I approach this problem and what should I be looking at?

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through all elements that have a specific class, for example 'popup' and add the popup functionality to those one by one:

```
var popups = document.getElementsByClassName('popup');

for (var i = 0; i < popups.length; i++) {
    popups[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
        // Add functionality here
    });
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2tb0g58f/)